# Why isn't my v210 format video showing as such through a V4L loopback device?

Tags: format, video-streaming, v4l2, v4l2loopback

In a user-space application, I'm writing v210 formatted video data to a V4L2 loopback device.  When I watch the video in VLC or other viewer, I just get clownbarf and claims that the stream is UYUV or other, not v210.  I suspect I need to tell the loopback device something more than what I have, to make the stream appear as v210 to the viewer.  Is there one more place/way to tell it that it'll be handling  a certain format?

What I do now:

```
int frame_w, frame_h = ((some sane values))

outputfd = open("/dev/video4", O_RDWR); 
// check VIDIOC_QUERYCAPS, ...

struct v4l2_format fmt;
memset(&fmt, 0, sizeof(fmt));
fmt.type = V4L2_BUF_TYPE_VIDEO_OUTPUT;
fmt.fmt.pix.width = frame_w;
fmt.fmt.pix.height = frame_h;
fmt.fmt.pix.bytesperline = inbpr;    // no padding
fmt.fmt.pix.field = 1;
fmt.fmt.pix.sizeimage = frame_h * fmt.fmt.pix.bytesperline;
fmt.fmt.pix.colorspace = V4L2_COLORSPACE_SRGB;

v210width = (((frame_w+47)/48)*48);  // round up to mult of 48 px
byte_per_row = (v210width*8)/3;       
fmt.fmt.pix.pixelformat = 'v' | '2' << 8 | '1' << 16 | '0' << 24;
fmt.fmt.pix.width = v210width;
fmt.fmt.pix.bytesperline = byte_per_row ;

ioctl(outputfd, VIDIOC_S_FMT, &fmt);

// later, in some inner loop...
... write stuff to uint8_t buffer[] ...
write(outputfd, buffer, buffersize);
```

If I write UYVY format, or RGB or others, it can be made to work. Viewers display the video and report the correct format.

This code is based on examples, reading the V4L docs, and some working in-house code.  No one here knows exactly what are all the things one must do to open and write to a video device.

While there is an easily found example online of how to read video from a V4L device, I couldn't find a similar quality example for writing.  If such exists, it may show the missing piece.

Comment: If I look at https://www.linuxtv.org/downloads/v4l-dvb-apis-new/uapi/v4l/yuv-formats.html I don't see support for v210 which is a 10 bit format.